# get Name having both gender Male and female

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

```
+---+-----+---+------+
| id| name|sal|gender|
+---+-----+---+------+
|  1|  abc|  -|     M|
|  2|  xyz|  -|     F|
|  3|  pqr|  -|     M|
|  4|kiran|  -|     M|
|  5|kiran|  -|     F|
+---+-----+---+------+
```

write sql query/spark sql to get Name having both gender Male and female

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by more cleaner way in dataframe.

```
scala> var dfd = Seq((1,  "abc",1,"M"),(2,  "xyz",2,"F"),(3,  "pqr",3,"M"),(6,  "abc",7,"M"),(4,"kiran",4,"M"),(5,"kiran",5,"F")).toDF("id","name","sal","gender")

scala> dfd.groupBy("name").agg(collect_set("gender").as("_both")).filter(size(col("_both"))>1).show
+-----+------+
| name| _both|
+-----+------+
|kiran|[M, F]|
+-----+------+
```

this will handle all the cases.hope it helps

Comment: This will also return if there are 2 same names with same gender, if I add one more row (1,abc,-,M) it will return Name : abc having Gender [M, M] but I want only name having [M and F]

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(gender) <> max(gender);
```

If you have more than two genders, then filter before the aggregation:

```
select name
from t
where gender in ('M', 'F')
group by name
having min(gender) <> max(gender);
```

Comment: @nagraj036 . . . Your question is tagged "sql", so I'm surprised you unaccepted the SQL solution.